# Find the general term for the sequence of no. of permutations of derangements of length n where adjacent to an element it was originally adjacent to.

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, permutations, derangements

I wonder if there are any means to obtain the general term for the sequence of no. of permutations of derangements of length *n* where adjacent to an element it was originally adjacent to. The sequence is [A288208](https://oeis.org/A288208).

[A related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309850/if-some-series-of-n-terms-is-deranged-what-is-the-probability-that-no-term-stan)

I have tried to use Graph Theory to deduce the relationship between [A002464](https://oeis.org/A002464) and [A288208](https://oeis.org/A288208), but I failed.

Is there any hints or ways to find out the general term?